# Revoking privileges for a Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, privileges

I am trying to revoke the `SELECT` privilege for Employee table using the Query

> `REVOKE SELECT ON  ODS_INSTALL.employee FROM ODS_INSTALL;`

Currently i am connected in as `SYSTEM` user, but after getting connected to `ODS_INSTALL` and firing the query as:

> select * from employee;

i am getting the output, but it should give a error regarding insufficient privilege.
What may be the issue?

Comment: Which schema contains your `EMPLOYEE` table? The way your queries look like, you probably have one in both schemas. And AFAIK you cannot `REVOKE` privileges on a table from its owner.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt EMPLOYEE table is under ODS_INSTALL schema and the actual query that i am firing is 
 `REVOKE SELECT ON ODS_INSTALL.employee FROM ODS_INSTALL;`
Can't a super user 'revoke' privileges from a table?

Comment: The owner of a table always has full grants on it - and they cannot be revoked. If you don't want `ODS_INSTALL` to have a privilege on the table, you must move it to a different schema.

Answer (score 3):

As in Oracle the schema *is* the user, as far as I can tell, you cannot [`REVOKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9020.htm) a privilege on a table from its owner.

Strange you didn't have an error, as on my test system (Oracle 11g):

```
(as system)
SQL> revoke select on sylvain.n from sylvain
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant
```

```
(as sylvain)
SQL> revoke select on n from sylvain;
revoke select on n from sylvain
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

(issuing a `GRANT` before does not change anything)

Basically, *object privileges* are designed to grant/revoke access to *your* objects from *other* users. Maybe you should move your table to a dedicated schema, and grant insert/update/delete to `ODS_INSTALL` in that schema?

---

If you *really really* need to restrict access to its own table to an user, the only way I can see is to use [*Virtual Private Database*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG007). Broadly speaking, you will [write a function that dynamically generate an extra `WHERE` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#CIHCAACD) that Oracle will automagically append to every user query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth_orders( 
  schema_var IN VARCHAR2,
  table_var  IN VARCHAR2
 )
 RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS
  return_val VARCHAR2 (400);
 BEGIN
  RETURN '1=0'; -- always false: "hide" all rows
 END auth_orders;
/
```

And install it using:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
    object_schema    => 'ODS_INSTALL',
    object_name      => 'employee',
    policy_name      => 'orders_policy',
    function_schema  => 'sys',
    policy_function  => 'auth_orders',
    statement_types  => 'select'
   );
END;
```

Take a look at [Is to possible to forbid access to tables in own schema - Oracle? <sup>[dba se]</sup>](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/is-to-possible-to-forbid-access-to-tables-in-own-schema-oracle) for some details.

Comment: What if we fire a `GRANT` query before revoking

Comment: @Abhishek Doesn't change anything: `grant select on sylvain.n to sylvain` => Grant succeeded. `revoke select on sylvain.n from sylvain;` => _ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant_

Comment: Whem i am firing(on Oracle 10g) `GRANT` query and then `REVOKE` i am getting `revoke succeeded` but as soon as i change the user to see whether the privilege is revoked or not i am still able to access data of `Employee` table

Comment: i am using a different user for revoking the privileges.
In my scenario (as SYSTEM) i am firing `GRANT`and then `REVOKE`on `ODS_INSTALL` user

Comment: @Abhishek I can't tell you more as I haven't Oracle 10 at hand. I doubt this would work though. Maybe Oracle Corp. has only _fixed_ the behavior of GRANT/REVOKE on 11g to correctly report the failure? I could only encourage you to wait few hours, maybe someone will come with a better answer...